# How can I add functionality to existing event handlers in Windows Phone 7 controls

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, event-handling, windows-phone

I made a custom windows phone 7 control which I call GhostBox that inherits from Textbox. I want to automatically run a method (named Update) from inside the Ghostbox class when the control gets focus (ie GotFocus).

How can I tie in to that pre-existing event (GotFocus)? Do I have to make a new eventhandler/delegates?

Currently, I have to access the GotFocus method for each GhostBox I create and call the Update method manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe to any event. Just override the void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e) method in your descendant class:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);

    // do your stuff - call your Update method 
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe I forgot about overriding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and event.

```
 protected virtual void GotFocus()
 {
      //Your code
 }  

  public delegate void GotFocusEventHandler(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e);
  public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `GetFocus` event:

```
base.GetFocus += (s,e) => Update();
```